# How to make preview jump to a specific line on startup

Tags: preview, command-line

I am using [TexLipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) for working with latex, producing pdfs as output. I have configured it to use preview as viewer using this command line:

```
open -a "/Applications/Preview.app" %fullfile
```

Where `%fullfile` is the name of the file to be opened. TexLipse supports the adding of a `%line` argument, that can be passed to the viewer to make it jump to the position where the cursor in the editor is at. However, I could not find a way or any documentation on how to pass that argument to preview. Can anyone explain how to achieve this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with LaTeX, you should use [Skim.app](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/skim-app/index.php?title=TeX_and_PDF_Synchronization) not Preview.app

Skim has [support for moving bi-directionally between LaTeX source and the PDF](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/skim-app/index.php?title=TeX_and_PDF_Synchronization), **to a specific line** in either the source or PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with Preview. It can go to a specific page, but that's as close as you can get. And I doubt that's baked into the CL access.

You can get the free Adobe Reader for Mac [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?platform=macintosh&product=10). It must be able to do this...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with Preview.app but it wasn't designed for this so it is a bit of a hack.

Turn on GUI scripting, then make a script that simulates pressing the down arrow, then call that script n times.